# Post text box value when checkbox is selected

Tags: php, html, checkbox

I want to post the text box value to the database when checkbox is checked and the form is submitted,how can i do this.My code snippet is,

Html:

```
<form name="form1" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<td>Accessories with computer<br>
Power Adapter<input type="checkbox" name="accessories[]" value="power adapter"><br>
Power Cord<input type="checkbox" name="accessories[]" value="power cord"> <br>
Monitor<input type="checkbox" name="accessories[]" value="monitor"><br>
Keyboard<input type="checkbox" name="accessories[]" value="keyboard"><br>
Mouse<input type="checkbox" name="accessories[]" value="mouse"><br>
<input type="text" size="10" name="others1" class="input-text" />
<input type="checkbox" name="accessories[]" value="<?= $_POST['others1'];?>" ><br>
<input type="text" size="10" name="others2" class="input-text" /><input type="checkbox" name="accessories[]" value="<?=$_POST['others2'];?>" ><br>
</td>
</tr>
</form>
```

php:

```
$accessories = implode(' ', $_POST['accessories']);
$query ="INSERT INTO ticket SET accessories  = '$accessories'";
$result = mysql_query($query);
```

I've also tried passing the checkbox value as a variable but value is not stored in database. Please suggest me.

the section of the form looks like,

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You mixed insert query with update query. The query should look like this

```
INSERT INTO ticket (acessiories) VALUES ('$acessories')
```

Comment: The query works fine, there are other fields in the database that i've not added here. The values for other checkboxes is stored just not for the one with the text box.

Answer (score 0):

```
<form name="form1" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="text" size="10" name="others2" class="input-text" onclick="document.form1.submit();" />
</form>

<?php

if(isset($_POST))
{

//Do insert query to insert into database
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you just forgot to mention the " action='filename.php' " in the form tag.

Answer (score 0):

hey refer following code,

```
<form method="post"> <input type="checkbox" name="check" /> <input type="text" name="txt" /> <input type="submit"  name="submit"/> </form>
<?php  $a=$_POST['checkboxname']; if($a) /* true when checkbox is checked */ { echo $_POST['textboxname']; } ?>
```